# How to share my laptop internet connection with Android Sony Xperia Tipo?

Tags: networking, android, reverse-tethering

My laptop  Dell Inspiron-1525 has Dell Wireless 1395 WLAN Mini-Card as the wireless network card.

Does this adapter support AP, can it work as Access Point?

If yes, can I connect with a Sony Xperia Tipo mobile phone with the above laptop using "Adhoc wireless network"?

Note: My laptop also has an ethernet controller: "Marvell Yukon 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller" through which I can share the internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

On the newest ubuntu :

System Settings -> Network -> Wireless -> Use as hotspot -> Accept to disconnect if connected -> IPv4 Settings - Share to other computers-> Check out the options for changing the password/SSID and other more advanced things.

And if then you should connect to the internet through ethernet port and share that connection.

Source : http://www.howtogeek.com/116409/how-to-turn-your-ubuntu-laptop-into-a-wireless-access-point/