# sharing a PC's internet connection to connect HTC One M8 device to the internet

Tags: networking, internet, android, connection

I've **HTC One M8** and in the settings there is an option called:"share a computer's network connection with this phone"
any one who use HTC One M8 can reach it by going to:

> 1. Settings
> 2. WIRELESS & NETWORKING
> 3. More{Data usage,HTC Mini+,NFC...}
> 4. Mobile networking sharing
> 5. USB networking setting
> 6. Internet pass-through{Share a computer's network connection with this phone}

After choosing this option, when connecting the device via USB to an internet wired PC, this should make the phone connect to the internet even if there is no WIFI or 4G. I am using **Ubuntu 14.04** and **android version of 5.0.2**.

The thing is that in windows it's is very simple: if you have "HTC Sync Manager" installed on your windows computer the phone can automatically connect to the internet via the computer and it works wonderful but on ubuntu...

(it creates the option to have your phone connected without WIFI or 4G and it's very healthy!)

A solution to this issue can come out of 2 ways:

1. finding a way to create use the software "HTC Sync Manager" on ubuntu

**or**

2. find a totally different way to connect an android device to the network of a wired computer

I've already viewed the following questions:

> [How to share a wired Internet connection with an Android phone (reverse-tethering)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67663/how-to-share-a-wired-internet-connection-with-an-android-phone)
>
> [Share internet from PC to unrooted android smart phone connected via USB cable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/609466/share-internet-from-pc-to-unrooted-android-smart-phone-connected-via-usb-cable)
>
> [How to share my laptop internet connection with Android Sony Xperia Tipo?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278910/how-to-share-my-laptop-internet-connection-with-android-sony-xperia-tipo)
>
> [How to share a wired Internet connection with an Android phone (reverse-tethering)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67663/how-to-share-a-wired-internet-connection-with-an-android-phone)

The thing is that the good answers in these questions are usefull for laptops users and I use an old **PC without WIFI**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for a solution for reverse tethering on my unrooted Android device as well, but could not find any.

Eventually, I developed my own app: ReverseTethering NoRoot. It works on all Android versions 4.0+ and on Windows, Linux and Mac.

It is available on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.floriandraschbacher.reversetethering.free).

Comment: I tested your product and I'm very impressed. It's working smoothly but it might a little difficult to configure at first.